# Do usb sound cards need driver

Tags: sound-card, usb-audio

My onboard sound card is gone and my mobo have no place for new pci slot. So I've decided to buy a new usb sound card instead. I am using windows 8.1 so the main problem would be driver support. Do usb sound card need just usb driver or need specific driver support from sound card company? And will there be any sound quality different between pic card and usb card? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would need a driver. However, depending on the model, the driver may be built in to windows. If a driver is needed, the manufacturer should include a disk, or at least a link to download the appropriate driver.  Sound quality would be dependent on the device you choose. Check out some reviews of the specific device you are considering, to see if other owners are happy with the sound quality and compatibility with your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Every plug and play device needs a driver. The driver source is the only thing to be concerned about.

USB sound cards are not exactly standard pieces of equipment.

The best option is **always** to go to the manufacturer website and download the driver directly from them. Their drivers are always up to date and very specific to your device.

If they don't have a driver on their website, you'll need to rely on Windows WinXP/7 automatically finding a driver...

So, depending on your OS and the age of the equipment:

- Win XP "Find New Hardware Wizard" might find the correct driver, especially if it's a generic one. I would not rely on this.
- Win 7/8 has a much better chance at finding the driver in their more extensive driver database, so if you just plug it in you have a good shot at Windows locating the driver for you.

What's the manufacturer/model?